# What is the reference of the pronoun "which" in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, relative-pronouns, reference

To be more precise, the verb in the dependent clause may be included, which requires "than" to be treated as a conjunction.

Cathy is more talented than he is.

Comment: It is correct if I say: The verb that may be included in the dependent clause requires "than" to be treated as a conjunction?

Comment: "Which" refers to the preceding clause "the verb in the dependent clause may be included". In your second example, "than" is a preposition with the comparative clause "he is" as its complement.

Comment: Thanks pal  ❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *To be more precise, the verb in the dependent clause may be included, **which** requires "than" to be treated as a conjunction*.

Expanding into two sentences and replacing ***which*** by a gerund noun phrase for the activity it implicitly refers back to...

> *To be more precise, the verb in the dependent clause may be included. **Including the verb in the dependent clause** requires "than" to be treated as a conjunction*.

Comment: Thanks a million :)